# I am getting the error of requireStack: [ '/app/routes/index.js', '/app/app.js' ] while deploying node application on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, web, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy the node and express application on Heroku but getting the error Application error. Further, I have added the Procfile and tried the different solutions from StackOverflow and other platforms but the error did not resolve yet. I add the screenshot of the code and the error through the Heroku log. Thanks.

Comment: place more details, like error. Provide feedback from `heroku logs --tail -a YOUR_APP`. Show your package json `scripts` object, as well as `.procfile` if any.

Comment: It works I just added the npm and node version in package.json. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.